# Design pattern for selective method visibility

Tags: c#, methods, visibility

Consider the following code

```
class SqlInstance
{
    private SqlInstance()
    {

    }
    public void Connect(string username, string password)
    {
        //connect
    }
    public void Disconnect()
    {
        //disconnect
    }
    //This method is not a singleton. Its one instance per key
    public static SqlInstance GetInstance(string key)
    {
        return new SqlInstance();
    }
}

class FileInstance
{
    private FileInstance()
    {

    }
   //no this is not a mistake. This connect has no parameters
    private void Connect()
    {
        //connect
    }
    public void Disconnect()
    {
        //disconnect
    }
    //This method is not a singleton. Its one instance per key
    public static FileInstance GetInstance(string key)
    {
        return new FileInstance();
    }
}


class DataManager
{
    SqlInstance GetSqlChannelInstance()
    {
        //if some logic
        return SqlInstance.GetInstance("dev.1");

        //if some other logic
        return SqlInstance.GetInstance("dev.2");

        //...and so on
    }

    FileInstance GetFileInstance()
    {
        //if some logic
        return FileInstance.GetInstance("fil.1");

        //if some other logic
        return FileInstance.GetInstance("fil.2");

        //...and so on
    }
}
```

The **DataManager** is a wrapper style class which a caller has to use to get instances of **SqlInstance** or **FileInstance**. The problem here is that the callers can call the **GetInstance** methods of the classes directly instead for going through the DataManger class. How do we solve this problem? Specifically, is there a pattern or mechanism which forces the caller to go through the **DataManager**? Is it possible to make the two **Instance** classes '*visible*' only to the **DataManager** class.

I know that making the two classes inner classes of the **DataManager** class will help solve the problem but I want to know if there are other '*better*' ways to do this?

**PS: Please ignore the class names and implementation. This is an example only and not taken from any real life code.**

**Language is C#**

Comment: Your programming language is Java ?

Comment: @BobCromwell It is C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class SqlInstanceManager:SqlInstance
    {
        private SqlInstanceManager(){ }
        public static new GetInstance()
        {
            return SqlInstance.GetInstance("key");
        }
    }
class SqlInstance
        {
            protected SqlInstance()
            {

            }
            public void Connect(string username, string password)
            {
                //connect
            }
            public void Disconnect()
            {
                //disconnect
            }
            //Make this protected. Now this class cannot be instantiated
            //and it cannot be called without inheriting this class
            //which is sufficient restriction.
            protected static SqlInstance GetInstance(string key)
            {
                return new SqlInstance();
            }
        }

       //And the same thing for FileInstance



     class DataManager
        {
            SqlInstance GetSqlChannelInstance()
            {
                //if some logic
                return SqlInstanceManager.GetInstance("dev.1");

                //if some other logic
                return SqlInstanceManager.GetInstance("dev.2");

                //...and so on
            }


        }
```

Now the caller can call all methods on SqlInstance except GetInstance and no one call call GetInstance on SqlInstance directly!

This solved another unexpected problem too: previously the returned SqlInstance could further call GetInstance on itself defeating the whole purpose of the factory!

Thanks to Dek Dekku for getting me thinking in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

My C# is rusty, but if the caller code is in a different assembly file (that is, your code is imported in the caller code) you can probably try the `internal` modifier.

<del>*EDIT*: Found a more fitting one: `InternalVisibleTo`</del>

<del>http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx</del>

Comment: This wont work as GetSqlChannelInstance needs to return SqlInstance which should be visible to the caller. Else the code wont compile.

Comment: What about creating an interface or abstact class from which SqlInstance and FileInstance descend and only make that one visible to the caller while keeping implementation hidden?

(BTW, you're right for `InternalVisibleTo` but `internal` should work on methods)

Comment: That is a great idea. If you can add it as an answer I will gladly accept it. Please make sure it is elaborate enough for everyone to understand. I would hate to create an answer myself and mark it so after I got the idea from you.

Comment: you can make the class public and the CreateInstance-Method internal.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to nesting SqlInstance and FileInstance - GetInstance are visible to other types (but their signatures imply that DataManager is associated with them) and only DataManager and no other types in the same assembly will be able to get instances of FileInstance and SqlInstance, as long as DataManager doesn't expose Token.

```
public class SqlInstance
{
    private SqlInstance() {}

    internal static SqlInstance GetInstance(DataManager.Token friendshipToken, string key)
    {
        if (friendshipToken == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("friendshipToken");
        return new SqlInstance();
    }
}

public class FileInstance
{
    private FileInstance() {}

    internal static FileInstance GetInstance(DataManager.Token friendshipToken, string key)
    {
        if (friendshipToken == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("friendshipToken");
        return new FileInstance();
    }
}

public class DataManager
{
    private static Token token;

    static DataManager()
    {
        Token.SetToken();
    }

    public class Token
    {
        private Token() {}

        public static void SetToken()
        {
            token = new Token();
        }
    }

    public SqlInstance GetSqlChannelInstance()
    {
        return SqlInstance.GetInstance(token, "dev.1");
    }

    public FileInstance GetFileInstance()
    {
        return FileInstance.GetInstance(token, "fil.1");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the caller must be able to see the type of the returned object, just using internal on this version of the code won't work, as stated in the other answer.

We can solve this creating an interface or an abstact class (This is probably one of the few cases where the latter might be preferable) from which SqlInstance and FileInstance descend. Then we can hide these concrete implementations from the caller.

```
interface AbstractInstance {
    // Some stuff here    
}



internal class SqlInstance : AbstractInstance {

    // Ideally nothing changes here

}

internal class FileInstance : AbstractInstance {

    // Ideally nothing changes here

}
```

Using `internal`, the concrete classes can have their visibility limited to the scope of the assembly they reside in, while the interface can be used globally.
Now we only need to change the Factory so that its return value relies on the abstraction rather than the implementation

```
 class DataManager
    {
        AbstractInstance GetSqlChannelInstance()
        {
            //if some logic
            return SqlInstance.GetInstance("dev.1");

            //if some other logic
            return SqlInstance.GetInstance("dev.2");

            //...and so on
        }

        AbstractInstance GetFileInstance()
        {
            //if some logic
            return FileInstance.GetInstance("fil.1");

            //if some other logic
            return FileInstance.GetInstance("fil.2");

            //...and so on
        }
    }
```

Obviously, any calling code that relies on the concrete implementations may stop working at this point.

Let me know if it works, BTW :D

Comment: if the classes SqlInstance and FileInstance are public but have internal GetInstance, you would achieve the same - no type from other assemblies can call GetInstance - but there would be no problem of depending on concrete implementation. 

And this doesn't solve the problem - types from the same assembly still can call GetInstance of FileInstance.

Comment: @Dek Dekku: Lisp is right. See my answer to see what I did. I thought that was what you meant. Also, it is not always possible to move classes to separate assemblies.